# Set DateTimeFormat culture diffrent than current culture in xamarin without value converter

Tags: datetime, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cultureinfo

The time format doesn't change

```
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-SA");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-SA");
        var clone = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;
        clone.DateTimeFormat = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-CA").DateTimeFormat;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = clone;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = clone;
```

Image of what in DataBase and What in UI

[image: DataBase Entry]

[image: UI Image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the sepecific data format directly:

```
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
```

Update:

[image]

Comment: No, the same problem

Comment: I print the value and it did change. See my updated answer.

Comment: If the current app language is arabic the date is arabic calender not Jan and Feb and so on, and the date in local database is normal like 12/15/2020 but the date appear as example 01/11/1443

Comment: How does 1443 come? I can't reproduce it on my side.

Comment: I edited the post and added Images, in UI it's Hijiri Calender

Comment: Does this problem happen to other language/datefromat?

Comment: No  problem using valueConverter for the same language, and no problem using diffrent culture use Chinese zh-Hans

Comment: OK, you can use valueConverter as a workaround. And if you can confirm the problem only happens to arabic language, you can open an issue [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues).